# here I found this error in my eclipse ide while creating spring starter project

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, spring-boot-starter

[this is the error I found when I opened my Eclipse]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9z3K.png)

I need help someone who can solve this error when I opened my eclipse at starting only I'm getting this error when I opened my eclipse requesting for help  while creating spring starter project